# mpi4py hanging in spawn in master-slave code and hydra_pmi_proxy zombies

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I was wondering if anyone has seen an issue I am running into with mpi4py:

The code has a list of tasks that it sends to slaves and spawns a fortran executable to run on a particular configuration. The fortran code executes very quickly, however between each task as it gets called there is a considerable hang. I'm not certain what causes it, but it would be a big help if anyone can spot an issue. The code can also run over the configurations in a serial mode, taking them in turn rather than using mpi4py, and there is no hang in that mode whatsoever.

The time for serial is:

```
real    0m12.323s
user    0m45.468s
sys    0m1.490s
```

while for the mpi4py version below:

```
real    2m2.796s
user    4m1.602s
sys    2m43.595s
```

I have noticed that there are a lot of hydra_pmi_proxy zombies lurking when the code runs:

```
29770 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29772 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29784 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29795 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29796 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29797 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29810 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29815 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29820 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29825 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29830 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29835 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29836 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29837 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29838 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29855 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29860 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29865 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29866 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29878 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29880 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29886 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29887 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29888 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29889 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29906 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29911 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29912 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29913 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29926 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29927 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy                              
29928 cor22     20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hydra_pmi_proxy
```

and I'm not certain why that is.

I had thought it might be down to some i/o issue as the fortran code writes to stdout, but when I changed the code so that it doesn't any longer it had no effect. Also it seems that the fortran code executes and completes, and the hang is somewhere in the python scripts. The code runs better on a node of one of the local clusters, and it eventually does what it should on my local machine, but the idea of using mpi4py was to speed things up, and this has slowed them down, so I am fairly scratching my head...

Also all of the print statements get spat out at the very end of the loop in super_master.py, not as the run progresses, which is puzzling me

Below is a dummy version of the code that has the same issue which i run as:

```
mpirun -np 1 python3 ./super_master.py
```

Thanks for any insight and sorry for the long post!

super_master.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD


for x in range(0, 3):
   new_comm=comm.Spawn(sys.executable,args=["master.py"],maxprocs=1)
   new_comm.Barrier()
   new_comm.Disconnect()
   print("finnished run ",x)
   os.system('{}'.format('rm */*out*'))
```

master.py:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python3

from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import time


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
commp = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()

processes=4
tasks=([StopIteration] * (processes))+[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

new_comm=comm.Spawn("/PATH/TO/slave.py", args=[],maxprocs=processes)

status=MPI.Status()


while tasks:
    new_comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, status=status)
    data=tasks.pop()
    print("on master received source: ",status.Get_source())
    print("On master sending: ",data," to:",status.Get_source())
    new_comm.send(obj=data,dest=status.Get_source())
    print("On master sent: ",data," to:",status.Get_source())

print("Finished All",rank)
new_comm.Barrier()
print("after barrier",rank)
print("rank", rank,"task",tasks)
commp.Barrier()
commp.Disconnect()
```

slave.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import time

comm = MPI.Comm.Get_parent()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
cwd=os.getcwd()

print("slave", rank," entering loop")

for task in iter(lambda: comm.sendrecv(data,dest=0), StopIteration):
    print("slave ", rank," recvd data", task)
    print("slave ", rank," going to sleep")
    directory=os.path.join(cwd,str(task))
    os.chdir(directory)
    info = MPI.Info.Create()
    info.update({"wdir": directory})
    print("before spawn in slave:", rank)
    new_comm=MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn("/PATH/TO/FORTRAN_EXECUTABLE",
                  args=[],maxprocs=4,info=info)
    print("after spawn in slave:", rank)

    new_comm.Barrier()
    new_comm.Disconnect()
    info.Free()
    os.system('{}'.format('sleep '+str(task*1.5)))
    os.chdir(cwd)


comm.Barrier()
comm.Disconnect()
```

**EDIT:**

Hi again guys,

It would seem that on my local machine the spawned python processes go to sleep while the fortran code runs:

```
17530 cor22     20   0  190044  25868  10056 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.83 python3                                      
17531 cor22     20   0  189924  25832  10020 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.33 python3                                      
17532 cor22     20   0  189920  25844  10040 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.24 python3                                      
17533 cor22     20   0  190036  25832  10024 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.82 python3                                      
17534 cor22     20   0  190040  25832  10024 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.32 python3
```

which doesn't seem to happen on the cluster. It seems this is what is slowing things down. If anyone has any ideas on how to prevent this behaviour I'd be very keen to hear about it!

On the cluster I can get pretty good speed ups vs the serial version if the task list is large. if the task list is small (<20 or so) there is not much of a speed up, It seems that things stick a bit when it first sets off, but as it moves through the list of tasks if the list is large enough it gets back on track. Again I am not certain as to why this would be, but if anyone has any suggestions I'd like to hear them.

Timings on the 16 cpu cluster for a run of 4 spawned processes, each of which has a slave running the fortran code on 4 processes:

```
Tasks    mpi4py       serial
10       0m28.109s    0m30.472s
20       0m47.166s    1m6.380s
30       0m48.586s    1m38.161s
40       0m56.258s    2m10.056s
50       1m5.508s     2m10.056s
100      1m31.854s    5m22.126s
200      2m18.955s    9m4.022s
```

Comment: I have the same problem (the fortran executable being multinest) - there are now hundreds of zombie hydra and python processes lurking on my compute nodes, I'm not sure why and it's definitely causing (at least) memory issues....